# Cannot validate properly the username and password using Array.Find()

Tags: c#, arrays, object, oop

I'm trying to make a username and login system to validate if the username and password passed by an user by input matches the username and password in an array of objects. I did using Array.Find() but when I run the program, the user and password are asked twice and I have to put them twice correct so I can advance which does not make sense...

```
        Utilizador[] usersIniciais = utilizadoresDefault.UtilizadoresDefault(utilizadoresDefault.GenerateID());
        PersonalTrainer[] ptsIniciais = ptsDefault.PTsDefault(utilizadoresDefault.GenerateID());

        int option = novoLogin.LoginInicial();
        Tuple<string, string> strings = novoLogin.DadosLogin(option);
        string username = strings.Item1;
        string password = strings.Item2;

        novoLogin.ValidacaoDados(username, password, usersIniciais);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

```
namespace RSGymPT.Classes
{
    internal class Login
    {
       
        public static void Log(string Username)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"User Logged: {Username}");
        }

        public int LoginInicial()
        {
            int option;

            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Seleciona a opção pretendida: \n");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Login");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Sair\n");

                Console.Write("A tua opção: ");
                Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out option);

            } while (option != 1 && option != 2);
            return option;
        }

        public Tuple<string, string> DadosLogin(int option)
        {
            if (option == 1)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Please insert your Login data: \n");
                Console.Write("User: ");
                Username = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Password: ");
                Password = Console.ReadLine();
                return Tuple.Create(Username, Password);
            }
            else if (option == 2)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("See you soon.\n");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            return Tuple.Create(Username, Password);
        }


        public void ValidacaoDados(string user, string password, Utilizador[] utilizadores)
        {
            Utilizador utilizador = Array.Find(utilizadores, element => element.NomeUtilizador == user);
            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("User: ");
                Username = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Password: ");
                Password = Console.ReadLine();
               if (utilizador != null && utilizador.Password.Equals(password))
                {
                Console.WriteLine("Login correct");
                }
               else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Bye");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
            } while (Username == null || Password == null);
        }

    }
```

```
namespace RSGymPT.Classes
{

    internal class Utilizador
    {

        public Utilizador[] UtilizadoresDefault(int id)
        {
            Utilizador[] usersInicial = new Utilizador[]
            {
                new Utilizador {Id = GenerateID(), Nome = "user1", NomeUtilizador = "user1user", Password = "user1234"},
                new Utilizador {Id = GenerateID(), Nome = "user2", NomeUtilizador = "user2user", Password = "user1234"},
            };
                return usersInicial;
        }

        #endregion
    }

}
```

I tried a lot of different approaches life foreach loop and array.firstOrDefault() but I keep with the same thing. Can someone kindly help me to find my mistake?

Comment: There's a lot more code here than you need in order to present your problem. Please reduce it to a [mre].

Comment: You say you tried "firstOrDefault", but you have the case wrong -- case matters! It's "FirstOrDefault". Furthermore, you don't show how you used it. It's impossible to show you where your mistake is when you don't show the details that matter and include a bunch of code that doesn't.

Comment: As a side note, `Username` is static but `Password` is not. You assign `Username` in the constructor, so it's going to get overwritten every time you do `new Login()` which you *never* do, at least not in what you've posted.